# When I installed lombok version 1.18.22 in eclipse, then I cant rename files

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

When I installed `lombok` version `1.18.22` in `eclipse` `2022-03`, then I cant rename files (`alt+shift+R`)

desired behavior: Need to rename variable in eclipse (java file)

---

error: I cant rename variables in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is related to the latest version of `eclipse: 2022-03`
This problem is fixed for me when I use the previous version of `eclipse: 2021-12`

Answer (score 0):

The issue tracker is a better place than stackoverflow for this sort of thing. [See this issue](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3134) - it's already fixed. A new release is imminent.

Comment: Its not fixed yes, and will be fixed in the next version of lombok
1.18.24
https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/milestone/21